# How to write a disk image to a USB stick while downloading it from a torrent?

Tags: bittorrent, disk-image

I am currently torrenting a bootable ISO image that I need to write to a flash drive. My download speed and my write speed to the drive are comparable, and to save time I was wondering if there is a way to burn the image to the drive as I am downloading it, rather than having to wait twice while the image downloads to my computer and then to the drive.

When downloading from a regular file URL, I can do this:

```
$ curl -L http://example.com/my-image.iso | tee my-image.iso | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX
```

However, torrents aren't downloaded sequentially in the same way, and in any case I don't know of a way to easily pipe a torrent download on the command line. I'd assume a solution would have to intelligently write out each piece of the file to the correct position as it is acquired, but I'm not sure how to do that or if there are tools that can do it for me.

How can I torrent an ISO image and simultaneously burn it to a flash drive/other block device?

---

In response to a comment: the specific ISOs I need to do this with are already configured in a way that lets me write them directly to the disk without need for modification (e.g. plain `dd` will work, no need for Unetbootin).
If there's a way to perform those modifications to allow using optical ISOs as well, that would be good, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: This is probably impractical to do; the .iso image requires some modification to work from USB vs. working from CD/DVD.  USB setup software such as unetbootin make these changes automatically, but they require a complete file so they can check integrity.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I've had success just `dd`-ing out ISO images that are specifically built for it. I know an optical disk ISO needs to be modified slightly. If there's a way to do it with optical ISOs too, that'd be great, but in this particular case I'm burning a USB-specific ISO image.

Comment: You can create a 'grub-n-iso' system in the USB drive. It means that grub points to an iso file (or  selects from many iso files in a multiboot system). In this case you can simply download the iso file directly to the USB drive. I have done it for isotesting Lubuntu using rsync (downloading only what is different in the daily iso file from yesterday), but it should be possible with torrent too. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682, for more details.

Comment: @sudodus You should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

### You can create a 'grub-n-iso' system in the USB drive

A 'grub-n-iso' system means that grub points to an iso file (or selects from many iso files in a multiboot system). In this case you can simply download the iso file directly to the USB drive.

I have done it for isotesting Lubuntu using rsync (downloading only what is different in the daily iso file from yesterday), but it should be possible with torrent too.

See this link for more details,

[One pendrive for all PC (Intel/AMD) computers - single-boot dual-boot multi-boot](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682)